# Is "dynamic" pattern-matching possible in OCaml?

Tags: dynamic, runtime, pattern-matching, ocaml

Well in Ocaml you can do this at compile-time :

```
let handle item = match item with
   | 1 -> "Do this";
   | 2 -> "Do that";
   | n -> "Do Nothing";
;;
```

Is there a way to realize it at runtime ? Like some kind of chain of responsibility pattern ?

Comment: Could you give a (pseudo)code example of what you want to do an runtime?

Comment: I hate it when people ask the same question on [two different channels](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1179894/autres-langages/langages-fonctionnels/caml/pattern-matching-dynamique/). A good way to ensure that helpful people waste time by duplicating explanation or comprehension of the problem. Please don't do that again. It may be true in the grand scheme of things that helpful people's time is a free resource that you can waste at will, but think of the humans behind the answers.

Comment: I agree with gasche. Next time you have an OCaml question, ask your question here and nowhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is such a pattern.

Let's assume that you're dealing with a function that must accept an integer and return a string, and that by default it will return `"Do nothing"` for every integer :

```
let func : (int -> string) ref = ref (fun _ -> "Do nothing") 

let _ = (!func) 1
- : string = "Do nothing"
```

If you wish to say that `"Do this"` should be returned when the argument is 1, you can do:

```
let () = 
  let old = !func in 
  func := (function 1 -> "Do this" | n -> old n)

let _ = (!func) 1
- : string = "Do this"
```